# Unable to install any Unity version from Unity Hub

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm looking into learning to use Unity, so I've downloaded the Unity Hub as it seems to be the way Unity is forcing us to download their versions from now on. The problem with this is that, every time I try to download any version of Unity through the Hub, I get a message once the download bar has completed along the lines of:

"Incomplete or corrupt download".

I've tried downloading plenty of different official versions, with various plugins, even without any add ons to start with, but I always get the same message.

I contacted Unity support, but they're insisting that it's my internet connection and I should download versions from the archives. Surely this can't be the case, as I can download everything else without any issues.

Has anyone else come across this issue and are there any solutions out there?

Comment: did you try downloading manually, just to see if the installer works? (since it downloads those files from web also) https://unity3d.com/get-unity/download/archive (select dropdown: downloads/unity installer)

Comment: Hey everyone. Sorry for the late reply on this. Had to take some time away from learning this.

I've installed Unity Hub version 2.3.2 and the issue seems to be fixed.

In the meantime, I had taken the advice and manually installed Unity without using the Hub.

Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 4):

**What I do :**

1) First of all ignored Unity Hub and install Unity manually

Download Link: *https://unity3d.com/get-unity/download/archive*

2) Download "Unity Editor 64 bit" or "Torrent download(Win+Mac)"

3) I download second one which also have other support file like Android, iOS, AppleTV etc.

4) Now Install "UnitySetup64.exe" application and other support files as your need and enjoy your project.

### Happy_Unity

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Do you have enough disk space to download the version? They can get big, if you install various modules with it.

While installing a new module it mentions the required disk space at the top.